# Refreshing Page After Timer End on Flutter Android Studio Timer Wont Countdown Again

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, timer

So im trying to make a screen that refresh every time there's a change on the database but after searching for tutorial i didnt get any.

so instead because i know how long in needed for the database table data to change, i just hard code it after the countdown the page will refresh it self and reread the database value. Heres the code

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sensor_detak_jantung/models/sensor.dart';
import 'package:sensor_detak_jantung/models/user.dart';
import 'package:sensor_detak_jantung/screens/authenticate/sign_in.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' as firebase_auth;
import 'package:sensor_detak_jantung/screens/doctor_menu/message_patient.dart';
import 'package:sensor_detak_jantung/screens/doctor_menu/patient_detail.dart';
import 'package:sensor_detak_jantung/services/db_path.dart';

class RecordPatient extends StatefulWidget{

  String email;
  RecordPatient({Key key,@required this.email}) : super(key : key);
  @override
  _RecordPatient createState() => _RecordPatient(email);
}

class _RecordPatient extends State<RecordPatient> {

  String email;
  _RecordPatient(this.email);

      final databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
      final _auth = firebase_auth.FirebaseAuth.instance;
      final TextEditingController tokenController = TextEditingController();
      User userInfo;
      firebase_auth.User _user;
      Sensor sensorInfo;
      final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
      String bpm;
      int avgBpm;
      int timeForTimer = 0;
    
      void initState(){
        super.initState();
        this._user = _auth.currentUser;
        if(_user != null) {
```

SO this is where i read the data from database

```
      databaseReference.child('Sensor').once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        bpm = snapshot.value['BPM']??"";
      });

      databaseReference.child('Sensor').once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        avgBpm = snapshot.value['AVG']??"";
      });

      databaseReference.child('Sensor').once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        timeForTimer = snapshot.value['TIMER']??"";
      });

      databaseReference.child(USER_KEY).child(_user.uid).once().then((snapshot) {
        userInfo = User.fromSnapshot(snapshot);
        setState(() { });
      });
    }
  }
```

And here is the timer where it should refresh. fortunately after refresh the timer didn't start again (not printing countdown on terminal) instead it just printing the BPM value.

```
  void timer(){
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) {
      if(timeForTimer < 1){
        t.cancel();
        setState(() {});
      }else{
        print(timeForTimer);
        timeForTimer -= 1;
      }
    });
  }
  
  AppBar title(){
    return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red[400],
      elevation: 0.0,
      title: Text('Hi ${userInfo?.userName}'),
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton.icon(
          icon: Icon(Icons.web_asset_rounded),
          label: Text('Save'),
          onPressed: () async {
            _auth.signOut().then((value) {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MessagePatient(email: email,avgBPM: avgBpm,)));
              setState(() {});
            });
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print (bpm);
    timer();
    return Scaffold(
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(22.0, 0.0, 22.0, 22.0),
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 40),
            title(),
            SizedBox(height: 40),
            Text (bpm),
            SizedBox(height: 40),
            Text('$avgBpm'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: the idea is that you don't need a timer, just wait for the data to arrive and the flutter will refresh the screen itself https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61075019/how-to-update-flutter-ui-according-to-firebase

Comment: it didn't change except i change screen and comeback