# Post Frame Callback - Looping

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been checking performance on my app and noticed that one of the widget constantly loops. in that Widget I am using the following code to retrieve data from Firestore DB, however for this example I have simplified it with the same looping result.

**Question: Is there a reason why Widget Binding is called so many times and in a loop? I was under the impression it was called once on widget build complete. Should I be using something else for a one off post build function?**

I have 7 of these widgets in a listView, so I should she maximum 7 I believe.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPersistentFrameCallback((timeStamp) async {
    print(' Is callback done?');
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          isLoaded = true;
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

The widget itself is very simple with just a Text Widget

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('Hello');
   );
  }
```

In my logs I see the following which just keeps going up and up and up.

[image]

Comment: As you now realize, the problem was addPersistentFrameCallback(), which invokes the callback over and over for every frame for the lifetime of the application.   The workaround was to substitute  addPostFrameCallback() instead. 
 But you still might want to consider other approaches. 
 For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61075285/3135317

Comment: @paulsm4 Thanks for the suggestion, but I have purposely opted to not use reactive/stream based approach for this app for various reasons. If I hadn't this would have been a good suggestion so I appreciate you taking the time comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you want `addPostFrameCallback` instead of `addPersistentFrameCallback` ?

As per documentation `addPersistentFrameCallback`:

> Once registered, they are called for every frame for the lifetime of the application.

As per documentation `addPostFrameCallback`:

> Post-frame callbacks cannot be unregistered. They are called exactly once.

Comment: That begs the question as to why the OP thinks they need ANY callback?   I'm also uncomfortable calling "setState()" instead of "initState()".  What's the goal, what's he/she trying to accomplish? 
 There's very probably a simpler/more effective way to do it...

Comment: Oh man, that's what happens when you use autoComplete in your IDE. Thanks for pointing that out. To answer @paulsm4 question, I am retrieving information from Firestore to populate my widget. I called setState at the end to refresh the widget with the data.

Comment: I just updated my code and it's fixed. Thanks again.